# Why am I getting Error "Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)" (related to openstack-dashboard)?

Tags: apt, dpkg, openstack

Whenever I try to use `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get upgrade`, I always get one error related to `openstack-dashboard`.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
The following packages will be upgraded:
  heroku
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/14.0 MB of archives.
After this operation, 190 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 413428 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (2:9.1.2-0ubuntu3) ...
Collecting and compressing static assets...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 18, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line  # noqa
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
dpkg: error processing package openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will get this error every time you upgrade or install a new package because package `openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme` is broken in your system.
Solution for this :

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme.*
```

Check if your problem is solved, if not then execute these command afterwards.

```
sudo apt remove --purge openstack-dashboard-ubuntu-theme
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt update
```